# vba test cells in columns for only listed words in any order with commas

Tags: vba

im trying to run test on columns for list of words in any order with commas included. i.e mars,earth, moon, sun  test only these words are in e columns if not error msg. could commas ie mars,sun or moon,sun my code is below im having issue with words that have commas and in differnt order pls help

```
Sub substring()

Dim Target As String, c As Range, lr As Long, ws As Worksheet

Dim Target2 As String

Dim Target3 As String

Dim Target4 As String

 

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6")

lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Target = "sun"

Target2 = "moon"

Target3 = "earth"

Target4 = "mars"

For Each c In Range("A2:B" & lr)

    If StrComp(c.Text, Target, vbTextCompare) And StrComp(c.Text, Target2, vbTextCompare) And StrComp(c.Text, Target3, vbTextCompare) And StrComp(c.Text, Target4, vbTextCompare) Then

        MsgBox c.Address

   End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we use a separate function to decide if there are any "bad guys" in any comma-separate list:

```
Public Function IsIn(s As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim arr, a
    arr = Array("sun", "moon", "earth", "mars")
    For Each a In arr
        If s = a Then
            IsIn = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next a
    IsIn = False
End Function

Sub kidus()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6")
    lr = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For Each cell In ws.Range("A2:B" & lr)
        arr2 = Split(cell.Value, ",")
        For Each a In arr2
            If Not IsIn(a) Then
                MsgBox cell.Address
            End If
        Next a
    Next cell
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Use this version of `IsIt()`:

```
Public Function IsIn(s As Variant) As Boolean
        Dim arr, a
        arr = Array("sun", "moon", "earth", "mars")
        For Each a In arr
            If LCase(s) = a Then
                IsIn = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next a
        IsIn = False
    End Function
```

Comment: @Gray's Student sorry is there way i can make it not case sensitive also? i.e Mars=mars

Comment: would i need somthing like this LCase(arr) = LCase(arr)

Comment: @Gray's Student it does not seem to work for me i put Lcase(arr)=Lcase(arr) in the function under where words are listed in the array im i putting in wrong place?

Comment: @KidusYohans  see my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @Gray's Student works perfect! thank you so much